# SSRS How to create a scheduled refresh for datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

So I have a view in MSSQL from which Power BI Cloud automatically reads data twice a day.

As Power BI has proven to be unreliable - refresh fails and etc. - we are looking into other alternatives.

Currently we have given people direct access to the MSSQL through Excel's Power Query, however as the query itself is a huge thing, we do not want 5~6 people to go click-refresh-happy all at the same time and cause any issues. Our query is simply CPU intensive.

So the other alternative which came to our mind was SSRS, hosted directly from our server and from which people can download an Excel copy and be on their merry ways.

Having not used SSRS at all, like ever, I am wondering if it has similar system to Power BI, in which you define a frequency of refreshes a day, and that makes it final. So like twice a day the Power BI dataset refreshes and it is what it is.

It seems that in SSRS everytime someone runs the report - and subsequently run the view - it refreshes.

How can we define a meaningful control over this? can we strict the dataset to be refreshed like once a day at 14:30PM for example? if so how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here a just a couple...

SSRS supports dataset caching. You can define a time period that a cached copy of the a dataset will expire, or you can specify that a cached copy expires on a schedule. Note that this does **not** refresh the dataset.

Let's say you set the expiry to 4 hours, that would mean the first person to run the report would execute the query and the dataset will be cached - this might take some time depending on your query. The next users to run the same report within the 4 hour window will re-use the cached copy of the dataset, if after 5 hours somebody runs the report, the query will be run again and the new copy of the dataset cached for the next 4 hours etc..

This has the advantage that if the report was not run for a day, the dataset query would not need to execute, the down side is that every four hours, the first user will get the hit of waiting for the query to run.

The other option would be to dump the results of your query into a table and schedule the process to run twice a day using an Agent job. Point the report to this table and your good to go.

This has the advantage that users will get the report results faster (unless they run the report whilst the refresh job is happening), the down side is that the query will be executed twice a day whether it's required or not.